# Database last consistent time unmatched

Tags: ravendb

When I'm setting up the website which uses the RavenDB it shows "Database last consistent time unmatched" exception.

I checked the rights and security for the RavenDB and it's correct.

Is there any other potential reasons why RavenDB couldn't open the database?

> Database last consistent time unmatched
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentConsistentTimeMismatchException:
>   Database last consistent time unmatched
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [EsentConsistentTimeMismatchException: Database last consistent time
>   unmatched]
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator
>   uuidGenerator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs) +561
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Could not open transactional storage:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\officecore.web\Website\App_Data/RavenDatabases/uCommerce\Data]
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator
>   uuidGenerator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs) +810
>
>   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration
>   configuration, TransportState transportState) +2056
>
>   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.InitializeInternal()
>   +449    Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize() +797    UCommerce.Search.RavenDB.RavenDbStoreProvider.SetupEmbeddedDocumentStore()
>   +675    UCommerce.Search.RavenDB.RavenDbStoreProvider.GetStore() +231    UCommerce.Search.RavenDB.RavenFacetedSearch.Query() +105
>
>   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.SearchLibraryInternal_FacetedQuery.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
>   +37    Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +116    UCommerce.Infrastructure.Interceptor.ExceptionLoggingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation
>   invocation) +625    Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>   +595    Castle.Proxies.SearchLibraryInternalProxy.FacetedQuery() +154    Officecore.Website.code.DataRepositories.ProductRepository.SearchProducts(String
>   searchterm, IList`1 facetList, List`1& products) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\officecore\officecore.web\Website\code\DataRepositories\ProductRepository.cs:210
>   Officecore.Website.code.DataRepositories.ProductRepository.SearchFacets(String
>   searchterm, IList`1 facetList, List`1& products) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\officecore\officecore.web\Website\code\DataRepositories\ProductRepository.cs:189
>   Officecore.Website.layouts.Officecore.Controls.Desktop.Desktop_Search_Facets.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\officecore\officecore.web\Website\layouts\Officecore\Controls\Desktop\Products\Desktop-Search-Facets.ascx.cs:57
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receiving this message it could be that database is corrupted.

To fix this try to run this script in the database folder where RVN is the name of the log file in the logs folder:

```
Esentutl /r RVN /l logs /i
```